# (Error) "make: *** No rule to make target 'caesar'. Stop." (in C)

Tags: c, terminal, directory, cs50

Everytime I make a directory and code and make a file as such, it works. For some reason, this is not working. You can see my work in the terminal and you can see the file structure. For some reason I am able to make "caesar.h" which makes no sense (of course I get an error when running "./caesar.h"). This is not a duplicate question because I know for a fact I'm in the correct folder. This is also strictly in C.

[image]

Comment: I just noticed a problem in your program `int main(int argc, int key)` is not a portable `main` function. Make it `int main(int argc, char* argv[])` instead. You can then convert the arguments given to the program with one of the conversion functions, such as `atoi` etc.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yes! After I was able to make the program, I faced the error, and changed it to that...thank you :)

Comment: I don't see how your question is related to C. Ad you can see, the error does not come from the C compiler, but from `make`. The relevant information would be your Makefile.

Comment: Please, don't make pictures of your code.  You will not be helped this way.  Just copy/paste the actual code.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it posts code in pictures that cannot be copy/paste'd and so, cannot be tested properly.

Comment: @LuisColorado the picture was vital to the problem because of the filing/directory situation.

Comment: @EAO123, and how did you reproduce it?  Why nothing is said in the question? Cannot you specify the filling/directory tree situation without an image.  Posting images makes it impossible to copy/paste your code.  We have to write it again by hand, and this makes the problem irreproducible.  Think twice before posting sources graphically, as only evident errors will be found.  I've seen you have already marked your answer as valid... so I'll not dig more in this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`make` may come with default rules for compiling certain files. It may compile `.c` files or `.cpp` files with different compilers for example.

`.h` files are usually not compiled directly. They are `#include`d by `.c` files  to become a part of the `.c` file's translation unit. There is most probably no built-in rule in `make` to compile your `.h` file.

Rename `caesar.h` into `caesar.c` and then try `make caesar`. My `make` has a default rule for `.c` files and compiles the program like so:

```bash
$ make caesar
cc     caesar.c   -o caesar
```

If that doesn't work, your `make` may *not* have a default rule, so you could create a `Makefile` in the `caesar` directory:

```
% : %.c
        $(CC) -o $@ $< -Og -Wall -Wextra -g -fsanitize=address,undefined
```

Note that the space before `$(CC)` must be a single <kbd>Tab</kbd> character.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't even notice that I had put .h instead of .c!

Comment: @EAO123 You're welcome! Easy mistake to make!